# Trouble trying to implement Gazebo's plowing model

Tags: ros, gazebo

I am currently working on my thesis which is focused on the mobility systems of 4 wheeled and 6 wheeled rovers, with a focus on the wheel-ground interaction. Because of this I really wanted to find a way to reproduce the deformability of the terrain on Gazebo (classic). I'm currently using the LeoRover Gazebo simulations having installed Gazebo through ROS (noetic). I really wanted to add to this simulation the wheel plowing modifications I found here https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/pull/3164, but I really can't get it working. I've downloaded Gazebo-classic on github and tried to start the .world tests for the plowing, they start up just fine (after adding the models to my ros gazebo model directory) but I do not notice any difference between the two tricycles. I'm not sure why that is happening, I believe that maybe the Gazebo I originally installed through ROS interferes with the simulation, I tried to compare the two gazebos and they have very different structures, the gazebo directory I dowloaded from github has .cc and CMakeLists files that the other doesn't have. I was only able to add the models and change the Collision.hh file. As you may notice I'm not really sure what I'm doing, any help at all would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Gazebo Classic or Gazebo Sim (Ignition / 'new Gazebo')?

Answer (score 2):

The plowing effect is currently only supported in gazebo-classic starting with [version 11.12](https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/blob/gazebo11/Changelog.md?plain=1#L110-L132); it is not yet supported in gz-sim. Can you confirm that the version of gazebo you are using is at or newer than 11.12, either through running `gazebo --version` or confirming the version number in your package manager?

I would use the following to run the example world:

```
# from root of gazebo-classic source tree
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$PWD/test/models:$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH
gazebo --verbose test/worlds/plowing_effect_tricycle_demo.world -u
```

This should start the simulation in a paused state. Once the world is loaded, click `View -> Contacts` and `View -> Transparent` from the gzclient window in order to see the contact point and normal directions. If you zoom in on the `plowing_effect_trisphere_cycle`, you should see the contact normal directions incline slightly after unpausing the simulation.

Comment: I noticed I was using Gazebo 11.11.0 so I tried to do sudo apt upgrade gazebo11, and it started updating, though at the end it said gazebo11 is already the newest version (11.11.0-1~focal). Could it be a compatoibility issue with my ubuntu version (Ubuntu 20.04.6)?

Comment: I managed to install Ubuntu 14.0.0 and through trial and error now the two tricycles have very different velocities! Thank you so much

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, you can try following the installation instructions that add packages.osrfoundation.org as an apt source: https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install