# Implementing Gazebo's plowing model in my <robot> urdf file

Tags: gazebo, urdf, ros-noetic, gazebo-plugin, sdf

In my previous question ([Trouble trying to implement Gazebo's plowing model](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105510/trouble-trying-to-implement-gazebos-plowing-model)), I tried to make the plowing approximation (https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/pull/3164/files) tests work as the author intended. I'd now like to make that work on my urdf model of the LeoRover rover. I previously had the .urdf.xacro file and converted it into a urdf. I tried to convert it into an .sdf and then add the <gz:plowing_wheel> to every wheel link. But in order for my simulation to work I must use a robot model, and I believe the convertion from sdf to urdf needed to do that doesn't work as intented or at all. If you want to take a look I could send my .urdf model or .sdf model.
I thank you all in advance for the help.

Edit: I've since given up on trying to apply it to my robot, instead I tried modifying the author example of the tricycles with spheric wheels by substituting them with cylindrical ones, unfortunately I've run into an unexpected behavior of the contact forces. I'd be grateful if someone could assist me with that.

Edit2: I've made a new model with 4 cylindrical wheels, the plowing model in this case just doesn't seem to alter the points of contact of those wheels, it just doesn't do anything. I'm starting to get really desperate. I thank in advance anyone who could lend an hand

Edit3: I dropped the plowing wheel model, I just could't make it work, instead I'll try to manually apply a resistance force on each wheel based on the compaction resistance equations illustrated by Genta's mechanics of space robots.